# Injecting into a static method/field with easymock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, powermock, easymock

I know that one of the rules for the easy mock is that it can not inject into static and final fields.

However,

if I have a code like:

```
public final class SomeClass
{
  private static final AccessInternet accInternet = AccessInternetFactory.getimplmentation();

  public static void startSomeWork()
  {
    final Customer cust = new CurrentCustomerDetails().getCurrent();
    ...
  }
}
```

So, without re-writing the code itself, can I write unit test for such class? Is there a way I can mock the Customer and inject it into startSomeWork()?

Using EasyMock and jUnit.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
Powermock.expectNew(Customer.class).andReturn(whateverSuitsYouAndCustomerClass).anyTimes();
Powermock.replayAll();
```

worked for me

Good luck!